# How to handle unfinished function call in java?

Tags: java, oop, coding-style

[image: the output looks like this]

```
import java.io.*;
    class LL_two {


        Node head;
        static class Node {
            int data;
            Node next;
            Node(int d){
                data = d;
                next = null;
            }
        }

        public void disp(int nth) throws IOException{
            Node n = head;
            int count = 1;
            while(count<nth && n.next!=null){
                n = n.next;
                count++;
            }
            //System.out.println(count);
            if(count<nth){
                System.out.println("No Search results; enter + number within 10 or 10");
                main(null);
            }


            while(n != null){
                System.out.println(n.data);
                n = n.next;
            }
        }

        public int sizeOf(){
            Node n = head;
            int count = 0;
            while(n != null){
                count++;
                n = n.next;
            }
            return count;
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{


            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            int nth = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            Node[] n = new Node[10];
            LL_two ll = new LL_two();
            for(int i =0; i<n.length-4; i++) {
                if(i==0){
                    n[i] = new Node(i+100+1);

                } else {
                    n[i] = new Node(i+100+1);
                    n[i-1].next = n[i];
                }
            }
            ll.head = n[0];
            ll.disp(nth);
            int c =ll.sizeOf();
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
```

Hi,

here's a simple single linked list implementation. The program displays the data from nth (which the user enters) Node to the last node. I've added 6 nodes to the linked list using a for loop.

The problem i'm running into is when the user enters a number greater than the linked list size, there are these other function jobs which aren't executed (but get added to a stack, i guess) (What this called?). These unfinished function calls get executed at the end. What is the efficient way to handle this?

Also, i'm trying to trying (learning) to maintain modularity. So I was thinking if i could use `sizeOf` function in disp to check if the user has entered a valid number. One way i could think of was by calling `sizeOf` and passing the argument `n` (which is nothing but `head`). But this makes the code less modular, doesn't it?

Any other inputs to improve this code, or my coding skills in general would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If the user enters invalid data, re-prompt them to enter valid data.

Comment: that's what i'm doing by calling main function again. is it good practice to call main function from other functions?

Comment: No, check the data input in main before continuing with any other logic.

Comment: Just so you know, by putting the Nodes in an array you are defeating the purpose of a linked list. All you should need in order to loop though the list is to create a Head Node and then add to its Next Node and so on and so forth. By putting the Nodes in an array you might as well just create an array of integers